# How to Accomplish the Same Things in Visual Studio Code as in Visual Studio (from a Debian-Based Operating System)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I do all of my work in Linux but I do understand that a Windows operating system can be essential sometimes. My university has all of its programming modules focused on C#. In the past this did not bother me as I was able to finish all assignments simply using Geany and Mono because of the simplicity of the tasks only involving console applications. For the future, I will be able to get by but I want to get extra marks for doing something more than console applications.

I had installed Windows 10 on my laptop with great success, however the problems came during use. Any installation of an update would send me down time-drain alley as I would constantly encounter the "Couldn't install updates, uninstalling updates now" loop in which I would have to restore to a previous memory point (not too bad, but timely) or I would have to reinstall the system if Windows made a backup of the system just as it was updating. Among others things, there would be a series of other issues as well.

I am running a Debian-based linux distro, and I got Visual Studio Code running pretty well with Microsoft SDK 2.2 and 3.0 installed, but I want to be able to figure out how to do more complex projects such as the WPF type. I have tried searching online for a long time but documentation seems sparse or it just seems to focus on the user interface rather than on compilation and coding, and I feel lost in my understanding of how to use Visual Studio Code. I see that other users find it intuitive, but I find it alien and I am wondering whether anyone would happen to know of any materials or even a book that would help me understand the complete ins and outs of using Visual Studio Code in a practical manner and how to construct the same applications as possible with Visual Studio in this cut-down-version?

I would be much obliged for any help in this matter.

Comment: VSC != VS. It is an editor, nothing more. With an extension they hooked up debuggers. Nothing of the fancy UI editors. Use the Community versions of VS. It's kind of the same with Java and JavaScript - name looks related but nothing in common. The JavaScript guys at Netscape just wanted to confuse. If they would have known how popular it would become.

Comment: I was hoping that I could do everything in Linux, but it looks like it will only be a dream for the moment. I found one solution in which to install Virtualbox with Windows 10 running so I can make use of Visual Studio, since VS is only available for Mac and Windows.